# Session values throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am passing session values from one page to another page as follows...

From `Page1`

```
Session["k3"] = "Val3"
Session["k4"] = "Val4"
Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
```

In `Page 2`, I am not getting values

```
public partial class Page2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        string k3 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["k3"].ToString(); //Not Working.
        string k4 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["k4"].ToString(); //Not Working.

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```

If i redirect to any other page, I am getting all `Session` values from `K3` to `K4`

What i tried:
On `debugging` all `Session` values are available till `Response.Redirect`

All `Session` Values are available for other `pages` in project, as i could see their result by opening other pages in another tabs.

I have double cross checked for `Session.Clear()` or `Session.Abandon()` but i have not used them in `Page2`

I could not understand what I am missing here.

Comment: What if you assign `k3` and `k4` inside the `Page_Load` event instead? You shouldn't rely on `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: Yes, working, if Assign happens insde `Page_Load` event

Comment: I would imagine that the session is not available at the time the page class is initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare and Assign in `Page_Load` event is working for this problem.

```
public partial class Page2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string k3 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["k3"].ToString(); //Not Working.
             string k4 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["k4"].ToString(); //Not Working.
        }
}
```